# Dropdown menu Bootstrap not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I talk about Angular because it's in my project but it's doesn't work in basics html website too.
I know this question have been asked multiple times but my dropdown menu doesn't work !
I just wan't to implement basics dropdown menu like:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<span class="dropdown-item-text">Dropdown item text</span>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

Just copied on bootstrap documentation.

So I see that this code in write in inspect mode in google chrome but not display in my website.

I have 1 error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
at Object.jQueryDetection (bootstrap.js:240)
at bootstrap.js:255
at bootstrap.js:9
at bootstrap.js:10
```

Because I have this error I check if jQuery have been declared before Bootstrap's.
I've got in angular.json (I also check the path) :

```
"style":[
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"src/styles.scss"],
"scripts": [
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"]
```

I use some other Bootstrap templates and that's work fine.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did u check the jquery in module if exists? generally jquery.min.js is written in angular node modules

Comment: I've got jquery.js and jquery.slim.js in node modules